# Conditional expectation when density of random vector is given

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

We have (X,Y) random vector with density
$$
g_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{y^3}{2}e^{-y(x+1)} & x, y \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Find $\mathbb{E}(X|Y), \mathbb{E}(X^2|Y^2), \mathbb{P}(X > 1|Y^3 + 1)$

Now, the first one was relatively easy:

I have found $g_Y(y)$ by performing:
$$
g_Y(y)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{y^3}{2}e^{-y(x+1)}dx =\frac{y^2}{2}e^{-y}
$$
Then 
$$
\mathbb{E}(X|Y) = \int_0^{\infty}x \frac{\frac{y^3}{2}e^{-y(x+1)} }{\frac{y^2}{2}e^{-y}}dx = \int_0^{\infty}xye^{-xy}dx = \frac{1}{y}
$$

Finally the answer is $\frac{1}{Y}$.

When looking for $\mathbb{E}(X^2|Y^2)$ I though that we need $g_Z(z)$ where $Z = Y^2$.

$$
F_Z(t) = \mathbb{P}(Z \leq t) = \mathbb{P}(Y \leq \sqrt{t}) = F_Y(\sqrt{t})
$$
Taking derivative w.r.t. t we get
$$
g_Z(t)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t}}\frac{t}{2}e^{\frac{t}{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{t}}{4}e^{\frac{t}{2}}
$$
How to proceed from there? I wanted to do something like
$$
\mathbb{E}(X^2|Y^2) = \int_0^\infty x^2 \frac{g_{(X^2, Y^2)}(x,y)}{g_{Y^2}(y)}dx
$$
but I have no idea how to get $g_{(X^2, Y^2)}(x,y)$.

What about $\mathbb{P}(X > 1|Y^3 + 1)$? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer for the first part is mainly correct, save that the conditional expectation is a function of $Y$, rather than $y$.$$\mathsf E(X\mid Y)=\dfrac{\int_\Bbb R x~g_{\small X,Y}(x,Y)~\mathrm d x}{\int_\Bbb R g_{\small X,Y}(x,Y)~\mathrm d x}=\dfrac 1Y$$

---

For the rest, note, since $Y>0$ is certain, then when given either $Y^2$, or $Y^3+1$, you are also given $Y$. $$\mathsf E(X^2\mid Y^2)=\mathsf E(X^2\mid Y)=\dfrac{\int_\Bbb R x^2~g_{\small X,Y}(x,Y)~\mathrm d x}{\int_\Bbb R g_{\small X,Y}(x,Y)~\mathrm d x}$$

Though, express the answer in terms of $Y^2$

Likewise 
$$\mathsf P(X>1\mid Y^3+1)=\mathsf P(X>1\mid Y)=\dfrac{\int_1^\infty g_{\small X,Y}(x,Y)~\mathrm d x}{\int_0^\infty g_{\small X,Y}(x,Y)~\mathrm d x}$$

And express the final answer in terms of $Y^3+1$

Comment: Calculating both integrals you've specified in $E(X^2|Y^2)$ left me with $\frac{2}{y^2}$ as result, which seems plausible(the result is then $\frac{2}{Y^2})$.

When calculating the second one though, I got $e^{-Y}$. Is there a mistake? How can I express that in terms of $Y^3 + 1$?

Comment: Since $Y>0$ most surely, therefore $$e^{-Y}=e^{-((Y^3+1)-1)^{1/3}}$$

Comment: Oh, right. Thank you very much! I did not truly understand why $E(X^2|Y^2)$ is the same as $E(X^2|Y)$ though. Is there a simple explanation to that?

Comment: Well, besides that the expected value of $X^2$ given a known $Y^2$ is the same as the expected value of $X^2$ given a value of $Y$ determined by knowing $Y^2$, there is the application of Jaccobian transformations (basically the chain rule applied to the derivatives of the CDF).$$\begin{align}g_{\small X,Y^2}(x,z)&=\left\lvert\tfrac{\mathrm d\surd z}{\mathrm d z}\right\rvert g_{\small X,Y}(x,\surd z)\\g_{\small Y^2}(z)&=\left\lvert\tfrac{\mathrm d\surd z}{\mathrm d z}\right\rvert g_{\small Y}(\surd z)\\[2ex]\therefore~g_{\small X\mid Y^2}(x\mid z)&=g_{\small X\mid Y}(x\mid\surd z)\end{align}$$